# Is there a way to download a particular LFS file from a given repository commit?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a repository and it has LFS files. I want to retrieve a particular LFS tracked file from a previuos commit, without affecting the working directory.

In other words, if I were to retrieve a non-LFS file (simple text file) from a previous commit, without changing the current working directory in anyway, I could do this:

```
git ls-tree -l -r <commit_id> | grep some_file.txt
git cat-file blob <blob_id> > some_external_directory_path/some_file.txt # blob_id is obtained from the previous command's output
```

What can be the equivalent for an LFS file? Because in the above way, only the file with LFS SHA details is retrieved, not the actual file.

Comment: Inside that blob, you will find an OID which identifies the file to download from the lfs file server.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `git cat-file --filters BLOB_ID`.  Note that you can also wrie this as `git cat-file --filters COMMIT_ID:some_file.txt`.

Using the `--filters` option applies filters, such as Git LFS, to the blob.  It can also be used for non-LFS blobs if you want a version of the blob with line ending or encoding changes applied.